# Why is this rational?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Why is ln($\pi^{\pi}$) rational?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not known if it is rational. It's suspected to be transcendental over $\mathbb Q$. It is known that $e^\pi$ is transcendental, but none of $e^e,\pi^e,\pi^\pi$ is known to be irrational or transcendental.